# How to display "loading..." on document title while page loading?

Tags: jquery, document, title

Im looking for a jquery code that replaces "loading..." with the document title and when the page is loaded it just removes and the default title comes back. Haha i know it sounds a bit crazy, but just like everyone says, "theres always a way". Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: Easily done without jQuery; are you using jQuery elsewhere on the page, too? Also: have you confirmed that there is a use case that will make this technique effective? If the load time is half a second, you won't really need "loading" to be displayed ANYWHERE. :) Also: you probably can't do this for initial load, only Ajax'd content... unless you want ALL pages to have "loading..." as their title right off the top.

Comment: My twitter loads in like half a second, yet, theres always that loading screen no matter what. It just makes the website function like an app haha.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I would try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var old_title = document.title;
  document.title = 'loading...';

  $(window).load(function() {
    document.title = old_title;
  });
});
```

Comment: Haha youre the boss. Works. Thanks!

Comment: Everything is possible with @Blender :D

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't need jQuery unless you are using it already.

Have the document's title by default as "Loading ..." (assuming) and when the document is ready, replace the title with whatever you want.

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.title = "Blah!";
});
```

Comment: Good, but it doesnt remove after load